# PowerShell (Azure Runbook) Error: Cannot find an overload for "Office365Tenant"?

Tags: office-365, csom, online

I need to create `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.Office365Tenant` object.

My PowerShell Script below runs fine on my LOCAL machine, using the specified assemblies:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
Add-type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll"


# Get instances to the Office 365 tenant using CSOM
$uri = New-Object System.Uri -ArgumentList $adminUrl
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($uri)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $pwd)
$o365 = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.Office365Tenant($context)
$context.Load($o365)
```

The issue I have is getting this to work in an Azure Automation PowerShell Runbook. I have loaded the assemblies and no longer get a missing assembly error, so I think I've ruled that out. But this line in the Azure Runbook:

```
$o365 = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.Office365Tenant($Context)
```

With the error:

```
    New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Office365Tenant" and the argument count: "1".

At line:32 char:9

+ $o365 = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.Offic ...

+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I can't figure out where else to look. The *Context* exists, Credentials are correct.

Comment: Double check you have the same version for the assemblies.  That error is happening because there's not a constructor for `Office365Tenant` that takes a single parameter.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll look into that. Although I zipped and imported the same assembly path into my Azure Automation Modules.

Comment: Looking at MSDN, there's only two signatures, and one of them expects a single parameter, so not sure why this would be throwing this exception.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was removing the Assembly References at the top of my script.

I guess Azure Runbook will grab these assemblies for me automatically.

One of those "Are you kidding me?" moments.